# Displaying Blackberry Push Notifications

Tags: java, blackberry, push-notification

I'm all setup in receiving push notifications. I am displaying a count with a icon on the top status bar. However I am unsure where to look next on how to display the message (possibly in the new Messages/Email view, like the twitter app).

I have all my messages persisted but no way to preview them when the status bar is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Messaging](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/Messaging-summary.html) guide from RIM? It describes how to set up a listener on the `ApplicationMessageFolder` that you can use to trigger your application.